# What does casting a theta(angle) to float do to amount?

Tags: java, android

In android studio I've been working on getting some imageviews to rotate and face certain coordinates. Using atan2 I've set the rotation of an imageview to this.

```
imageview.setRotation((float) 

atan2(imageview.getY()-<coordinate y wanted to face>,
      imageview.getX()-<coordinate x wanted to face>)

);
```

I noticed everytime I ran this line of code it faced the same direction each time.(The direction its facing in the drawable resource, and yes the method that runs it actully works)

So does casting the result of atan2(theta result) into float cause it to lose its value or something?

I know I can use matrix if I have to, but I'm experimenting with more efficient code.

EDIT: Turns out atan2 returns in radians...(1 radian=57.3 degrees )

Comment: Note that the return value of `atan2()` is in _radian_, not _degree_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of `atan2()` is in radian, while the parameter taken by `setRotation()` should be in degree.

You should change into

```
imageView.setRotation((float)Math.toDegrees(atan2(..., ...)));
```